# How to download intext images with beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to use beautiful soups and requests to program a website scraper in Python. I can easily collect all of the text I want but some of the text I'm trying to download has inline images that are important. I want to replace the image with it's title, and add that to a string I can parse later, but I'm not sure how to do this.

This is an example of the kind of HTML I'm trying to parse:

```
    <td colspan="3"><b>"Assemble under Siegfried!"</b> 
        <a href="/wiki/index.php/File:Continuous.png" class="image" title="CONT"><img alt="CONT" src="/wiki/images/thumb/7/78/Continuous.png/14px-Continuous.png" width="14" height="17" srcset="/wiki/images/thumb/7/78/Continuous.png/21px-Continuous.png 1.5x, /wiki/images/7/78/Continuous.png 2x">
        </a> This unit gains +10 attack for each 
        <a href="/wiki/index.php/File:Black.png" class="image" title="Black"><img alt="Black" src="/wiki/images/thumb/7/71/Black.png/15px-Black.png" width="15" height="15" srcset="/wiki/images/thumb/7/71/Black.png/23px-Black.png 1.5x, /wiki/images/thumb/7/71/Black.png/30px-Black.png 2x">
        </a> and 
        <a href="/wiki/index.php/File:White.png" class="image" title="White"><img alt="White" src="/wiki/images/thumb/8/80/White.png/15px-White.png" width="15" height="15" srcset="/wiki/images/thumb/8/80/White.png/23px-White.png 1.5x, /wiki/images/thumb/8/80/White.png/30px-White.png 2x">
        </a> ally besides this unit.
    </td>
```

From this HTML I want to pull:

> "Assemble under Siegfried! CONT This unit gains +10 attack for each Black and White ally besides this unit."

Using the normal `get_text()` method does not include the titles of the images, which is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ohh... I got what you need.

Try this:

```
html_data = """ <td colspan="3"><b>"Assemble under Siegfried!"</b> 
    <a href="/wiki/index.php/File:Continuous.png" class="image" title="CONT"><img alt="CONT" src="/wiki/images/thumb/7/78/Continuous.png/14px-Continuous.png" width="14" height="17" srcset="/wiki/images/thumb/7/78/Continuous.png/21px-Continuous.png 1.5x, /wiki/images/7/78/Continuous.png 2x">
    </a> This unit gains +10 attack for each 
    <a href="/wiki/index.php/File:Black.png" class="image" title="Black"><img alt="Black" src="/wiki/images/thumb/7/71/Black.png/15px-Black.png" width="15" height="15" srcset="/wiki/images/thumb/7/71/Black.png/23px-Black.png 1.5x, /wiki/images/thumb/7/71/Black.png/30px-Black.png 2x">
    </a> and 
    <a href="/wiki/index.php/File:White.png" class="image" title="White"><img alt="White" src="/wiki/images/thumb/8/80/White.png/15px-White.png" width="15" height="15" srcset="/wiki/images/thumb/8/80/White.png/23px-White.png 1.5x, /wiki/images/thumb/8/80/White.png/30px-White.png 2x">
    </a> ally besides this unit.
</td>"""
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = BeautifulSoup(html_data, "html.parser")

texts = [html.find("b").get_text()]
for a in html.find_all("a"):
    texts.append(a.attrs.get("title"))
    texts.append(a.next_element.next_element.next_element.strip())
print(" ".join(texts))
```

---

I don't sure that you realy want. But i purpose need attrs of Tag.

Example:
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```
html = BeautifulSoup(html_data)
for a in html.find_all("a"):
    print(a.attrs.get("title"))
```

Output:

```
CONT
Black
White
```

If you want download images:
    from urllib.parse import urljoin
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```
cdn_url = "http://some.com/" # root url of site with static content
html = BeautifulSoup(html_data)
for img in html.find_all("img"):
    img_response = requests.get(urljoin(cdn_url, img.attrs.get("src"))) #img content should save in file
```

Answer (score 0):

The output you expected to have from the above html elements is not that easy to achieve (at least to me). However, I've tried one which will fetch you the exact output you required.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

content="""
<td colspan="3"><b>"Assemble under Siegfried!"</b> 
    <a href="/wiki/index.php/File:Continuous.png" class="image" title="CONT"><img alt="CONT" src="/wiki/images/thumb/7/78/Continuous.png/14px-Continuous.png" width="14" height="17" srcset="/wiki/images/thumb/7/78/Continuous.png/21px-Continuous.png 1.5x, /wiki/images/7/78/Continuous.png 2x">
    </a> This unit gains +10 attack for each 
    <a href="/wiki/index.php/File:Black.png" class="image" title="Black"><img alt="Black" src="/wiki/images/thumb/7/71/Black.png/15px-Black.png" width="15" height="15" srcset="/wiki/images/thumb/7/71/Black.png/23px-Black.png 1.5x, /wiki/images/thumb/7/71/Black.png/30px-Black.png 2x">
    </a> and 
    <a href="/wiki/index.php/File:White.png" class="image" title="White"><img alt="White" src="/wiki/images/thumb/8/80/White.png/15px-White.png" width="15" height="15" srcset="/wiki/images/thumb/8/80/White.png/23px-White.png 1.5x, /wiki/images/thumb/8/80/White.png/30px-White.png 2x">
    </a> ally besides this unit.
</td>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"lxml")
part1 = soup.select_one("td > b").text.strip('"')
part2 = ' '.join(''.join([''.join([item['title'], item.next_sibling]) for item in soup.select("td a")]).split())
print("{} {}".format(part1,part2))
```

Output:

```
Assemble under Siegfried! CONT This unit gains +10 attack for each Black and White ally besides this unit.
```

Let us not do this again.

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can do this is by iterating over the contents of the `td` tag. I feel this is a bit easy to understand.

```
html = '''<td colspan="3"><b>"Assemble under Siegfried!"</b> 
    <a href="/wiki/index.php/File:Continuous.png" class="image" title="CONT"><img alt="CONT" src="/wiki/images/thumb/7/78/Continuous.png/14px-Continuous.png" width="14" height="17" srcset="/wiki/images/thumb/7/78/Continuous.png/21px-Continuous.png 1.5x, /wiki/images/7/78/Continuous.png 2x">
    </a> This unit gains +10 attack for each 
    <a href="/wiki/index.php/File:Black.png" class="image" title="Black"><img alt="Black" src="/wiki/images/thumb/7/71/Black.png/15px-Black.png" width="15" height="15" srcset="/wiki/images/thumb/7/71/Black.png/23px-Black.png 1.5x, /wiki/images/thumb/7/71/Black.png/30px-Black.png 2x">
    </a> and 
    <a href="/wiki/index.php/File:White.png" class="image" title="White"><img alt="White" src="/wiki/images/thumb/8/80/White.png/15px-White.png" width="15" height="15" srcset="/wiki/images/thumb/8/80/White.png/23px-White.png 1.5x, /wiki/images/thumb/8/80/White.png/30px-White.png 2x">
    </a> ally besides this unit.
</td>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
final_text = []

for content in soup.find('td').contents:
    if content.name == 'a':
        final_text.append(content['title'])
    elif content.name == 'b':
        final_text.append(content.text.strip())
    else:
        final_text.append(content.strip())

print(' '.join(final_text))
```

Output:

```
"Assemble under Siegfried!"  CONT This unit gains +10 attack for each Black and White ally besides this unit.
```

Or, a *dirty* one-liner:

```
final_text = ' '.join((x['title'] if x.name == 'a' else (x.text.strip() if x.name == 'b' else x.strip())) for x in soup.find('td').contents)
print(final_text)
```

Or, even better, using a function name similar to `get_text()` to get the text of the `td` tag:

```
def get_modified_text(td):
    return ' '.join((x['title'] if x.name == 'a' else (x.text.strip() if x.name == 'b' else x.strip())) for x in td.contents)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
print(get_modified_text(soup.find('td')))
# "Assemble under Siegfried!"  CONT This unit gains +10 attack for each Black and White ally besides this unit.
```

**Note:** If you don't want the quotes `"` around the first text, just use `.strip('"')`.

Comment: @ElleryBuntel, if you need any explanation for any line of code, feel free to ask.